# Replace tags of selected buttons to the remaining buttons

Tags: ios, tags, uibutton, frame

Here there are n `UIButtons` and when selecting a particular `UIButtons` it is removed from `SuperView`. The remaining buttons frame's are moved to this point. Similarly trying to replace the tags of other buttons with selected buttons. This is what I have tried so far.

```
-(void)totesttheFunction
{
    for(int i=0; i<7; i++)
    {
        UIButton *testHere = (UIButton*)[self.view viewWithTag:i];
        if([testHere isSelected])
        {
            int backuptagFor = testHere.tag;
            CGFloat diff = 30.0;
            for(int j=i+1; j<7;j++)
            {
                UIButton *btnToReplace = (UIButton*)[self.view viewWithTag:j];
                 CGRect setRect = CGRectMake(btnToReplace.frame.origin.x-diff, btnToReplace.frame.origin.y, btnToReplace.frame.size.width, btnToReplace.frame.size.height);
                btnToReplace.tag = backuptagFor;
                [testHere removeFromSuperview];

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here integer variable difference is the difference in frames between two adjacent UIButtons.

Answer (score 2):

I dont know for what purpose you are using this code.

But UICollectionView will be a better approach to solve your problem.
Add multiple buttons in collectionview cell .
then collection view will itself manage the deletion and index of each cell.

Comment: I am using this for the purpose of a card game..So wen 1 card is selected it is removed and remaining cards are moved to this frame[difference between the two adjacent uibuttons]..

Comment: For your problem UiCollectionView can be used. In collectionView you can give different frame to cell and you can easily delete cells in collectionview cell with animation and for further calculations use index of cells

Comment: the problem now is that i have completed the remaining part of the project.. it is now stuck at this point. to change to collectionview at this time is little tough.

Answer (score 0):

In my understanding the solution can be like below.

Adding buttons to view

```
for (int i=0; i<7; i++) {
        UIButton *btn = [[UIButton alloc]init];
        btn.tag=i;
        CGRect frame=CGRectMake(0, i*40, 90, 37);
        [btn addTarget:self action:@selector(btnDidPressed:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
        [btn setFrame:frame];
        [btn setTitle:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Button %d",i] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

        [self.view addSubview:btn];

    }
```

Removing the pressed button

```
-(IBAction)btnDidPressed:(id)sender
{
    UIButton *btn =(UIButton *)sender;

    [btn removeFromSuperview];

}
```

Also you can rearrange buttons with in view subviews or store buttons in an array. While pressed button remove selected one and redraw remain buttons.

Comment: i was able to move the frames of the remaining buttons to removed btn position but how will i replace the tags of those removed buttons with remaining btns

Answer (score 0):

Initialize an array that stores buttons. [array addObject:btn] in viewdidload method.

Then you can remove selected and replace the other buttons like below. btnDidPressed method:

```
UIButton *btn =(UIButton *)sender; //Pressed button 

CGRect rect = btn.frame; //pressed button frame
CGRect temp ; 

int tag =btn.tag; //pressed button tag
[btn removeFromSuperview]; //remove from view
[arr removeObjectAtIndex:tag]; //remove from array

for (int i =0; i<arr.count; i++) {
    UIButton *btnNew = [arr objectAtIndex:i];
    NSLog(@"tags old %d new %d",tag,btnNew.tag);
    if (btnNew.tag>tag) { //be sure not to move previous buttons 
        temp = btnNew.frame;
        [btnNew setFrame:rect];
        btnNew.tag=i; //change tag
        rect = temp;
        [self.view addSubview:btnNew];
    }

}
```